# h2 database: Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file

Tags: java, h2

As the title reads, I am trying to open a `.h2.db` file using `DataGrip` on `MacOS`. However, I keep getting the error

```
Unsupported database file version or invalid file header in file
```

With the error code

```
[90048-192]
```

How do I check the actual database file version and how to get the correct driver files(?) ?

Comment: What's the version currently in use? I would try adding the upgrade JAR to classpath

http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#database_upgrade

Comment: Another idea to try would be to force disable MVCC by explicitly connecting with ;MVCC=FALSE http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#mvcc

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was with the `JDBC URL` in the h2 login screen.
It was a random URL and after I changed it to the `spring.datasource.url` value I had set in my application.properties, it started working.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with a persistent TCP H2 database.

After updating the H2 version, the old persisted database file still existed.

I had to delete the old database file to get rid of the error.

My Error Code was `[90048-214]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with a database tool like SQuirreL to your database and execute `SELECT H2VERSION() FROM DUAL` or `select value from information_schema.settings where name = 
'info.VERSION';` to get the actual version.

Maybe this link on how to upgrade a h2 database can also be helpful: [How to check if a h2 database needs to be upgraded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094815/how-to-check-if-a-h2-database-needs-to-be-upgraded)

One more thing: your database could be corrupted. You could try to recover the data by using the recovery tool http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#using_recover_tool or to check the database on corruption [How to check h2 database health and corruption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32727588/how-to-check-h2-database-health-and-corruption)

Comment: So maybe it's not a false version but a corrupted header?